# How to block/Disable Sitecore analytics for GDPR regions?

Tags: xdb, xconnect, cookies

This code is only droping the cookies from the cookie board, the analytics is still on for the user. Is there any way to disable/enable `xdb.enabled` to false/true based on country region.

```
if (countryCode != "IN" && countryCode != "US")
            {
                if (HasCookieConsent())
                {
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE"] != null)
                    {
                        var myCookie = new HttpCookie("SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE");
                        myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
                    }
                args.AbortPipeline();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Did you try using the `Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Current?.EndTracking();` before aborting the pipeline as given in this article? https://blog.baslijten.com/sitecore-analytics-cookie-consent-and-personalization-isnt-a-great-match-learn-how-to-keep-sitecore-functional-without-breaking-the-law/

Answer (score 0):

`Xdb.Enabled` is a Sitecore setting and it can't enable/disable on the fly with code changes. It can be patched using Sitecore patch file to enable/disable it and update the value to true/false.

patch file:

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
   <sitecore>
     <settings>
       <setting name="Xdb.Enabled" set:value="false"/>
     </settings>
   </sitecore>
 </configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably try to add new module to web.config to remove `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE` if the IP address is located in certain countries. You could you services like https://www.iplocation.net/ and its API to ask which country this IP address is located. Then you compare that country name from Sitecore or file that contains `GDPR` country list.

In order to handle this scenario this way is to create a new `IHttpModule` like this:

```
public class CheckCountryHttpModule : IHttpModule
{
    public void Init(HttpApplication context)
    {
        context.PreSendRequestHeaders += PreSendRequestHeaders;
    }

    private void PreSendRequestHeaders(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpApplication app = sender as HttpApplication;
        if(Sitecore.Context.Database == null || Sitecore.Context.Database.Name == "core" || app.Context.Request.RawUrl.StartsWith("/sitecore")
        {
            return;
        }
        // Check location based on ip address
       if(IsLocatedInGDPRCountry(app))
       {
          // Remove Sitecore AnalyticsCookie from response
       }
    }

}
```

Lastly, you need to add this to `web.config`  section

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
        <add type.....
        <add type="namespace.CheckCountryHttpModule, AssemblyFile" name"CheckCountryHttpModule" />
</modules>
<system.webServer>
```

Although you have to know that if user is behind a VPN, the country can be different than where the real user is.

Comment: Can you please, show how you have removed SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE ?

Comment: to remove cookie you can just do app.Response.Cookies.Remove("SC_ANALYTISC_GLOBAL_COOKIE") so it wont go back to user browser

Answer (score 0):

By adding the mentioned code in the question :-

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE"] != null)
                    {
                        var myCookie = new HttpCookie("SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE");
                        myCookie.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
                        HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(myCookie);
                    }
                args.AbortPipeline();
```

`SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE` will no longer use, `args.AbortPipeline()` disable `SC_ANALYTICS_GLOBAL_COOKIE` automatically.

Answer (score 0):

What you are already doing is good enough for the cookie to be deleted.

I think you can try disabling the analytics tracker with the below line, before deleting the cookie:

```
Sitecore.Analytics.Tracker.Enabled = false;
```

This should stop Sitecore from tracking the user.

I hope this helps. :)